# Keeping multiple Apache servers in sync

Tags: apache-2.2, rsync, lsyncd

**Overview**

Currently my company runs 5 web servers that hook into 1 DB/Fileshare server.  The DB/Fileshare server uses NFS to mount on the 5 webservers so we only have to update the code once because the web servers read from the mount ( PHP/HTML ).


**Problem**

We have been hitting a bottleneck with the NFS mount recently and were wondering what possible options we have?  I can put the files on the web servers but what is the correct way to sync these files across them? I do not think rsync is the right approach but are there other options like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just the web code (not the DB) then you would be better off using GIT or some other source code management tool with automation (Puppet?) to push code updates to all servers.

Comment: Yes it would just be web code but potential problem could be user uploaded documents.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the size and volume of document files?

Comment: Currently there are 2 types of docuiments.  PDFs and CSV.  The PDFs are usually around 300 - 400 KB and I say about 50-100 are uploaded daily.  CSVs happen nightly and can be any size.

Comment: I agree that the volume of documents and their sizes would not be good for GIT. Maybe time to split the code and user data. Keep the web code on a local server drive using GIT to manage. Keep the documents on the NFS drive but look at how to optimise NFS. Or maybe move from NFS to an alternative.